# How to filter search on your View using server side processing?

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1kZH.png)I have view and have list of fields from the table on my database, i am using dataTable, but i want to implement my search, to filter all available field names from the table. When they are not available must be able to read from the database. I have no experience to do this, can any mates show me with examples to do this please. Below is my logic on View side, is there way also to on Controller class? if so please show me.

```
    // Index.cshmtl

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "EventManagement List";
    }
    <hr/>
    <hr/>
    <hr/>
    <h2>EventManagement List</h2>
    <table id="EventManagementTable" class="display">
        @*Semantic UI*@
        @*<table id="EventManagementTable" class="ui celled table">*@
        @*Bootstrap*@
        @*<table id="EventManagementTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">*@

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>TrainingID</th>
                <th>TrainingType</th>
                <th>TrainingDescription</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Venue</th>
                <th>Facilitator</th>
                <th>WhoAttend</th>
                <th>RSVP</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>TrainingID</th>
                <th>TrainingType</th>
                <th>TrainingDescription</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Venue</th>
                <th>Facilitator</th>
                <th>WhoAttend</th>
                <th>RSVP</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

    </table>


    <!--Normal DataTables-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.20/datatables.min.css" />

    <!---JQuery ThemeRoller-->
    <link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--Semantic UI-->
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.semanticui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    @section scripts{

        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.semanticui.min.js"></script>
        <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

        <script>

         $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#EventManagementTable").DataTable(
                    {
                        "ajax": {
                            "url": "/EventManagement/GetList",
                            "type": "GET",
                            "datatype": "json"
                        },
                        "columns": [
                            { "data": "TrainingID" },
                            { "data": "TrainingType" },
                            { "data": "TrainingDescription" },
                            { "data": "Price" },
                            { "data": "Facilitator" },
                            { "data": "WhoAttend" },
                            {"data":"RSVP"}
                        ],

  "serverSide": "true",
                    "order": [0, "asc"],
                    "processing": "true",
                    "language": {
                        "processing":"processing...... please wait"
                    }


                    });

            });
        </script>


        }
// Controller
 [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult GetList()
        {
            //Server side Parameter.
            int start = Convert.ToInt32(Request["start"]);
            int length = Convert.ToInt32(Request["length"]);
            string searchValue = Request["search[value]"];
            string sortColumnName = Request["columns[" + Request["order[0][column]"] + "][name]"];
            string sortDirection = Request["order[0] [dir]"];





            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Check Below Link: For server side datatable Processing https://stackoverflow.com/a/60147374/6880498

Comment: @Deepak the server side is done on Model class? Or right after my Jquery dataTable for pagination?